# How to restore docker frozen on vim

Tags: docker, vim, dockerfile

Hi I was working on a docker container and was inside vim when vim suddenly froze. I could not come out of vim so I had to close that terminal. When I reattach with that docker instance I am thrown back to that frozen state.

How do I kill vim on the docker instance or reattach without being thrown back into the frozen state ?

If I commit the docker now will it save itself with the frozen state ?

Thanks

Comment: not an answer but have you tried :q! in the vim terminal?

Comment: Another try would be `ctrl+q` to send an `XON` have a lock here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72086/ctrl-s-hang-terminal-emulator

Comment: I tried ctrl+q - does not work. Cursor keeps blinking. ESC does not respond so no chance of trying :q!. I have to kill the terminal session - but how ? - moment I attach to the instance it puts me back to the same state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer

docker exec -it `<container id>` bash

This lets you enter the container using a new bash prompt. Then you can kill -9 the offending vim process and that's it.